# How get the attributes from a feature properties in openlayers?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, openstreetmap, geoserver

I'm using openlayers with GerServer

and **I want to get a specific attributes from feature properties** for the building I've clicked

so how to customize the return value when click the polygon

e.g. (if I want to get just LAND attribute in this example below)

[image]

here is my code to get the data when click the polygon

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('buildingInfo').innerHTML = '';
    var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
    var source = allBuildingLayer.getSource();
    var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            evt.coordinate,
            viewResolution,
            'EPSG:3857',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}
        );
        if (url) {
            fetch(url)
            .then(function (response) {
                 return response.text();
            })
            .then(function (html) {
                 document.getElementById('buildingInfo').innerHTML = html;
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: If the server supports it you could use INFO_FORMAT application/json and it would be easy to select individual properties from the result.

Comment: yes the server supports application/json, but who to select the individual properties from the result.

Comment: See https://codesandbox.io/s/getfeatureinfo-tile-forked-ugi4r